# How to install Remote Desktop Virtualization Host role service in Hyper-V 2012 R2

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, hyper-v, remotefx

I am using the free Hyper-V 2012 R2. I am trying to add RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter to one of my VMs. I have installed a dedicated GPU for this. However when I go to "add hardware" I get the error: "Hyper-V cannot add a RemoteFX 3D video adapter to this machine because the Remote Desktop Virtualization Host role service is not installed. Install the role service and then try again."

Comment: When you say "the free Hyper-V 2012 R2", exactly which version did you install, and in what form? when you check the roles available to install, is the RDVH role listed?  Have you ensured you're using the latest video drivers for your card?

Comment: Question resolved: for reference, this is the OS I was referring to. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn205299.aspx

Comment: Answer: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574158.aspx